# How to retrieve value from the below given tags

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, findby

This is from one of our web application. I want to retrieve value 8 to compare it against value from database.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "p_Power Reactors_planned")]
public IWebElement Planned_PR { get; set; }

string PRPlanned = Planned_PR.GetAttribute("p");
```

HTML:

```
<p class="big" id="p_Power Reactors_planned">8</p>
```

I am getting empty result string.

Comment: Have answered it, please let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong command to retrieve the text

`GetAttribute();` is used to retrieve the value of attribute of an HTML tag

e.g.  `<p class="big" id="p_Power Reactors_planned">`

`GetAttribute("class");`  - You will get value `big`

`GetAttribute("id");` - You will get value `p_Power Reactors_planned`

You have to use `.Text` method to get required text

e.g `string PRPlanned = Planned_PR.Text;`

As per HTML rule if your element fall under given tags [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) then you can use `GetAttribute("value");`

Answer (score 1):

As "8" is displayed as an text in the given tag, you can fetch it by using `string PRPlanned = Planned_PR.Text`

Answer (score 0):

The text **8** is the *textContext* of the `<p>` tag. So you need to use the `GetAttribute("innerHTML");` method as follows:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "p_Power Reactors_planned")]
public IWebElement Planned_PR { get; set; }

string PRPlanned = Planned_PR.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```